# Failing to send a Cookie in GET Request despite {withCredentials:true}

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I intend to implement a simple login app with Spring Boot REST API, JWT(Auth0 -**java-jwt**), and Angular 8. After login, I am receiving a Cookie from the REST API as follows:

```
Cookie cookie= new Cookie("token",token);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setDomain("localhost");
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
    //cookie.setSecure(true); - for deployment
    httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

In the browser(Dev tools, Response headers), I can see the Cookie received, with the correct token. However, I can't see it in `chrome://settings/siteData?search`, I tried Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox, all showing the same results.

Now, this is how I am sending my request from the Angular client:

```
const h = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", "Bearer ");
this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/users", {headers:h, withCredentials: true })
```

In the request headers, I am not seeing this cookie, and for that reason,  I suppose, the request does not get authorized.

[image]

What is it that I am missing? Also, I appreciate any articles that demonstrate a simple login with Spring Boot (REST API only, not with Thymleaf or something), Angular and JWT (java-jwt). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion here the problem is that you are sending an Authorzation header without the JWT, in fact you are writing in your code `const h = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", "Bearer ");`.

I had solved a similar problem with fetch in a react application, but I guess that it should be the same for you, without setting Authorization header but setting like you withCredentials: true.

at the end m suggestion is try to remove the header due to with your configuration you does not sending the JWT token

**TIPs** if in your question you have written a blank token but in your actual production code you are inserting it properly perhaps you should check if your resource server works fine with I do not know... postman curl or something like that
or you should check that your token is a valid token and not an expired token

p.s. in your backend server implementation I saw a very low level details I suggest you to use Spring Security oauth2 module if you are useing a spring boot 2.x or Spring Cloud Security OAuth2 if you are using a Spring Boot 1.5.x version